# What is the Best Linux OS for Samsung 900x?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I was just wondering if you can recommend me a Linux OS for my Samsung 900x laptop. I just want to familiarize myself with the Linux OS and I know companies like people who uses Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should ask this kind of questions in linux forums.
depending on your hardware and knowledge level you can choose a distro to use.
for example if you want to just use your OS out of the box, you can use distributions like Linux Mint and Ubuntu.
**I recommend you to try a live linux disk like Knoppix which has some Desktop environments installed.**
then you can choose what Desktop you like (Gnome shell, KDE, xfce,...)
and if you ever wanted to install linux on hard disk, you at least know what you want.
good luck and welcome to GNU/Linux world!